# Group by an evaluated field (sql server)

Tags: sql-server

Regarding the SQL Server “group by” clause, the following SQL statement works:

```
select
  convert(datetime,ROUND(convert(float,InHistoryDate),0)) as date,
  Payername as clientname,
  SUM(COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC(TotalCharge), 1) AS MONEY), TotalCharge)) as total_char,
  SUM(COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC(HCPSaving), 1) AS MONEY), HCPSaving)) as savings,
  SUM(1) as claims
from EquianClaimSystem.dbo.LongHCFA1500BMHistory
group by InHistoryDate, Payername
order by 1
```

The following SQL statement does not work:

```
select
  convert(datetime,ROUND(convert(float,InHistoryDate),0)) as date,
  Payername as clientname,
  SUM(COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC(TotalCharge), 1) AS MONEY), TotalCharge)) as total_char,
  SUM(COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC(HCPSaving), 1) AS MONEY), HCPSaving)) as savings,
  SUM(1) as claims
from EquianClaimSystem.dbo.LongHCFA1500BMHistory
group by 1, 2
order by 1
```

Why can’t I use numbers in the group by clause to reference the evaluated result of a field rather than a straight field name in SQL Server?

Is there a way around this?